# What's the easiest way to generate a binary number of variable length consisting of all 1's in Java

Tags: java, binary

I have a variable called length.

I want to generate a binary number consisting of all 1's which is the length of my variable.

e.g. length = 4
     result = 1111

I've tried arithmetic shifting a 1 in a for loop, but I can't seem to get it to work.

edit: This is not my homework! I'm not even a student!

For those asking for an attempt, this is what I've tried:

```
        int test = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i<length;i++){
            test >> 1;
        }
```

Comment: Please post your attempt.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You could try `(1 << length) - 1` if 31 bits will always be enough.

Comment: what datatype do you want the result as? an `int`? something else?

Comment: And if you're after a `String`, there's always `Stream.generate(() -> "1").limit(length).collect(joining());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending if you need a String or an int, how to get it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int length = 14;

        //To provide a string
        String res1="";
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) res1+='1';
        System.out.println(res1);

        //To provide an int
        int res2=0;
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) res2+=Math.pow(2, i);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(res2));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to shift `1` by `n`, generating `2^n`, then subtract `1` to get `2^n - 1`, which is all ones in binary:

```
int result = (1 << length) - 1;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

Explanation: Powers of two have a binary representation of one followed by `n` zeros (`10000` for `n=4`) and can be generated by shifting `1` to the left `n` times. To get to this number by counting up in binary, the previous number has to be a sequence of ones (e.g. `1111` for `n=4`). So we just need to compute the corresponding power of two and subtract one to get the desired sequence of ones.